# unable to print table data on blade file in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

need print Task table task_name column values in index.blade.php file

this is index.blade.php

```
@if(isset($tasks))
@foreach ($tasks as $task)
<h1>{{ $task->task_name }}</h1>
@endforeach
@endif
```

TasksController.php is

```
 public function index()
{
    $tasks = Task::all();

   return view('tasks.index')->withTasks($tasks);
}
```

No any error message but do not print data...how to fix

Comment: in index.blade.php (at the top) write `{{dd($tasks)}}` and display output on above question

Comment: an error message Undefined variable: tasks (View: C:\Users\Lilan\Desktop\aca\resources\views\tasks\index.blade.php)

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
return view('tasks.index')->withTasks($tasks);
```

to

```
return view('tasks.index')->with('tasks', $tasks);
```

or

```
return view('tasks.index', array('tasks' => $tasks));
```

and try again.

**Explanation:**

The second parameter of the view function is the the array that contains the data in it on different indexes. As an alternative to passing a complete array of data to the `view` helper function, you may use the  with method to add individual pieces of data to the view.

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#passing-data-to-views)

Comment: an error message Undefined variable: tasks (View: C:\Users\Lilan\Desktop\aca\resources\views\tasks\index.blade‌​.php)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
return view('tasks.index')->withTasks($tasks);
```

with

```
return view('tasks.index',['tasks'=>$tasks]);
```

And try again.

Comment: an error message Undefined variable: tasks (View: C:\Users\Lilan\Desktop\aca\resources\views\tasks\index.blade‌​‌​.php)